# Traveling cross loops from 1 to 0 in r

Tags: r

im stuck with some troubles analysing a DataBase

i need to travel trough every column and row from a DB, and each of the cells are integer numbers like 1,2,3,4,5 or **0**. 
Now i need to make a loop from 1 to these numbers, make a aleatory multiplication, and then sum the results of the experiment.

My problem is that a lot of times the loop is from 1 to 0 and that is apeareantly leaving holes in the dataframe so it doesn´t run.

here is the code for you to see

```
A1#Big Dataframe with 0s 1s 2s .... (frist column is a code so it doesn´t count as data
RI1=data.frame()                                      
I=NULL                                                
I1=NULL                                               

for(k in 2:ncol(A1)){                                 

  for(j in 1:nrow(A1)){                               

    for(z in 1:A1[j,k]){                              

      if(A1[j,k] == 0){                               

         RI1[j,k]=0                                   
         I1=0                                         

         } else{                                      

         Pv=(qbinom(runif(1), 10, 0.5))/10 

         I=Pv*Datos$maximo_pagado[j]                  

         I1=rbind(I1,I)                               

         }
    }                                                 
    RI1[j,k]=sum(I1)                                  
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output.

Comment: A1= [1,2,3:2,1,0]

in the second iteration z=2 A1[1.2]=2

1) I=0,45*1000 I1=[450]
2) I=0,52*1000 I1=[450, 520]

end iteration 2

Comment: Alter your initial question with the code included please